# OneToMany ManyToOne removing child object with Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, one-to-many

I'm using Spring Boot and Hibernate.
Lets assume we have two entities:

```
@Entity
public class A{
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "objectA",fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval=true)
    private Set<B> objectSet = new HashSet<>();
}
@Entity
public class B{
    @ManyToOne
    private A objectA;
}
```

And we have two transacional methods;

```
deleteB_X(int idB){
    entityManager.remove(entityManager.find(idB,B.class));
}
deleteB_Y(int idB){
    B obj=entityManager.find(idB,B.class);
    obj.getObjectA().getObjectSet().remove(obj);
}
```

What I understand (correct me if I'm wrong):

1. We have `orphanRemoval=true` so `deleteB_Y(int)` will work.
2. By setting `mappedBy` argument we say that class A is "the owning
   site" of relation.
3. CascadeType is used when we persist/update/merge/remove class A (then it invokes persist/update/merge/remove on child property `objectSet`). I think we can say that it protects me from situation where I end up with object of B and no object of A class (unless we manually add some B objs).

From what I understand CascadeType should not interfare with orphanRemoval, because CascadeType takes care of things where we do 'some stuff' with A's objects (and then recursively do it to B's objects). And here is something that I don't understand at all.
Why `deleteB_x(int)` doesn't work and why if we remove CascadeType it starts working? I feel like that `deleteB_X(int)` is much cleaner solution to removing object B from the DB than `deleteB_Y(int)`, but sadly it won't work since it colides with CascadeType.

EDIT1.
Method `deleteB_X(int)` just doesn't remove object from DB, if we remove `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` evertyhing works just fine. Why?

Comment: 1: yes. 2: no, it's the reverse. 3. no idea what you mean. 4. the end of your question implies that deleteB_X() doesn't work. If your question actuall is "why doesn't it work, then ask that, explain what "doesn't work" means precisely, and post all the relevant code.

Comment: @JBNizet 3.I meant that to make `CascadeType.ALL` do antyhing we have to persist/merge/remove object that is instace of A.class not other way around. Basicaly if we add `A` obj that has 2 items in `Set` in DB we will have 2 object in table `A`.

Comment: If you persist an A, and this A has two Bs, no, you won't have two As in ddatabase. Why would you? You'll have one A and two Bs. Note that adding a transient B to a managed A will automatically persist the B, even without a call to persist(A).

Comment: @JBNizet I added some clarification. Is it necessary to copy-paste my code? I mean i tried to make it simple to make it easier to find a solution. My code has exactly the same method, but instead of `A` and `B` there are my class names.

Comment: Yes, post a complete minimal test case reproducing the error. Removing a B shouldn't cause any problem.

Comment: @JBNizet I'm really sorry about that message. Of cources we will have one A object and two B's... I meant that and I'm not sure why on earth I wrote something completly diffrent.

Comment: @JBNizet added body of the methods that I exactly use.

Comment: @JBNizet not sure if u saw it but I added my code

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that my `class A` was fetched `EAGER` in `class B` instance and because of that (I assume) that there was a conflict when I was deleting `B`'s instance alone without taking care of the same `B` instance in  `private Set<B> objectSet`. Changing `EAGER` to `LAZY` or excluding `CascadeType.PERSIST` from `@OneToMany(cascade=...)` solved my issue.